# Prove that in a cyclic quadrilateral $ABCP$ where two of its sides are equal the ratio $ {PA\over PB + PC}= {AC\over BC}$ is constant for any point P

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction, quadrilateral

Let *ABC* be an isosceles triangle where $AB = AC$. Consider the circumference in which the points *A*, *B* and *C* live. Let *P* be a point in the chord of this circumference formed by the points *B* and *C*. 
[image]

Prove that the ratio:

$$ \frac{PA}{PB + PC}= \frac{AC}{BC}$$

is constant for any point $P$.

Comment: I can not draw the picture according to your description., especially when P is in the chord BC and ABCP is a cyclic quad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Ptolemy's Theorem, $$(PA)(BC)=(PB)(AC)+(PC)(AB)$$ Since $ABC$ is iscoceles, $AB=AC$, so $$(PA)(BC)=(PB)(AC)+(PC)(AC)=(AC)(PB+PC)$$
And we get $$\frac{PA}{PB+PC}=\frac{AC}{BC}$$